# Disable CodeAnalysis for VS2010 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, fxcop

I have around 50 projects in a solution and most of the projects (except unittest projects) have enabled RunCodeAnalysis. The problem is that, build is taking a lot of time. Even if I modify a source of a file it is building all the projects.

Assume a project takes around 10s for build and 8s is taken by CodeAnalysis itself. So, Just want to disable CodeAnalysis at solution level, without going to each project and disable it. The change I want to have it at local and I don't want to check-in this change to TFS.

Therefore I can build faster without Code Analysis.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well your project file is in source control so this change would be transported to the Server.

You could write a tool which removes write protection and remove the section in the visual studio project file and run it on every get. This is a little ugly.

Better would be if you make a convetion that you get a custom build configuration "WithoutQA" which you can check in, and when you work with it you can set it to this one.
But this means that you should communicate this with your team (which is the better solution)

see also: [MSDN Build Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

and [MSDN Understanding Build Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kkz9kefa.aspx)

You can set diffent options for each Build configuration so also the QA Analyse options:

Screenshot form MSDN:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here, slow compilation and slow code analysis.

Concerning speeding up the compilation process, some tips are provided in this White-Book: [Partitioning code base through .NET assemblies and Visual Studio projects](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Assembly.pdf). If you are using the VS option `Copy Local = true`, there are chances you can speed up compilation by a large factor (up to 10x faster).

Concerning code analysis, you can try the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Default.aspx) that comes with more than [200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html), and that is very fast to check these rules in VisualStudio. It should takes 2 or 3 seconds to reanalyze all your VS solution (after compilation) and check all rules, with facilities to browse rules result. (*Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of this tool*).